# In Flink how to join a table with itself and compare incoming message with value in state

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

```
CREATE TABLE kafka_table (
  id INT,
  id_array ARRAY<INT>
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  'topic' = 'your_kafka_topic',
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka_broker:port',
  'format' = 'json',
  'json.fail-on-missing-field' = 'false' -- Allows fields to be optional in JSON
);
```

I have a table definition as above, I am trying to achieve this
example event : `id_1, [e1, e2, e3]`

I want the out as separate event to kafka as : `[id_1, e1, not_deleted]  [id_1, e2, not_deleted]  [id_1, e3, not_deleted]`

Now if **e3** is delete I get an event
example event : `id_1, [e1, e2, e4]` 
now I want the output to look like : `[id_1, e1, not_deleted]  [id_1, e2, not_deleted]  [id_1, e3, deleted]   [id_1, e4, not_deleted]`

Is there a way to join the same table with itself to achieve this. I would probably need use a UDf or table function to compare incoming kafka event against what in state for a key and collect some data.

Then use `LATERAL VIEW explode(new_id_array)` and publish this.

How to achieve this only using Flink SQL code ?

Comment: It seems you want something like [upsert-kafka](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/connectors/table/upsert-kafka/) ?